# Clicking on Second img with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to click on the second img in this html code, as shown in the highlighted row in the image below.

This line: 
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img[src="/images/excel.png"]').click()`

clicks on the first img, which extracts the excel file for 2020.
How do I skip the first img (2020) and click on the second img (2019)?

[Image of HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JuMY.png)

Comment: You're going to need to share the link to the page you're working on, or the HTML code itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_elements...` instead of `find_element...`.

Then access the second element of the result like

```
result[1]
```

as indices are zero based.